# When I was learning CS61a, I ran into this problem, why does the first one get the correct answer, while the second one throws an error

Tags: computer-science

[image]
[image]

The first one prints 3 correctly, while the second one throws an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.